# Creating a parent with childrens as a list, starting from a list that have child-parent relations

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a database I have a table, where I have a ForeignKey to itself(depth is the depth level in the multi-tree):

```
id name depth   path   parent_id
 1   A    0     1         Null
 2   A1   1     1,2       1
 3   A2   1     1,3       1
 4   A11  2     1,2,4     2
 5   A111 3     1,2,4,5   4
 6   B    0     1         Null
 7   C    0     1         Null
```

I get with a query all categories from the database. The depth can be infinite.

When I get a query from the database, I make from each record and object.

I need, that each child object to be attached to the parent, as an element in a list attribute:

```
 for item in items:

   create object A 
   has a A a parent; no - do nothing
   create object A1
   has object A1 a parent; yes A.list[0] = A1 
   create object A2
   has object A2 a parent; yes A.list[1] = A2
```

After the list was created I need to retrieve back:

```
  for item in items:
    item.name
    has item.name A children - yes 
    -> for itemAkid in itemAchildren:
     itemAkid.name
```

Comment: Will the query include all data for the hierarchy? Or are additional queries needed to load those?

Comment: And is this database structure fixed? It's not an efficient structure to handle subtree queries (you'd be better off with a closure table for that).

Comment: Recommended tag: `database`

Comment: @MelvinAbraham: this is not really a database question, not if the query already contains all the information to reconstruct the tree.

Comment: @MartijnPieters   yes the query will include all the data

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have besides depth also a path.  I have hundreds of items with parents with multiple depth levels up to 5 but can be more; Because I need to show the all tree(and reverse) I presume is faster to do it in python instead of queering hundreds of times the database.

Comment: @user3541631: A closure table would let you efficiently query a complete subtree from any node reference. The database can generate the paths for you too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I query all the tree at once, quering subtrees again are at least tens of queries in database; besides I'forced to use an ORM, so I don't have full control over the query.

Comment: @user3541631: the ORMs I know for Python still give you good control over queries. SQLAlchemy and Peewee certainly do, but Django's built-ins ORM can be taught too (or you can use a [dedicated library](http://django-closuretree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

Comment: @MartijnPieters is Django

Comment: Then use `django-closuretree` and stop worrying about having to query the whole tree when you only need a subset. And when querying you'll get the tree with correct parent references without manually having to build the objects.

Comment: Or use [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) for a different SQL model for hierarchies, or [django-treebeard](https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard), which can handle 3 different structures.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I cannot I have to work with something that is already implemented

Comment: These projects can be made to work on top of already created models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your query produces the rows for complete subtrees.

You can trivially create the relationships if you *sort* your query to go in depth-reversed order, and to keep the nodes created for the previous depth around as a dictionary from parent id to object.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(id, name, children=()):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.children = children

query = '''\
    SELECT
        id, name, parent_id
    FROM <TABLENAME>
    WHERE <CRITERIA>
    ORDER_BY depth DESC
'''

cursor.execute(query, (parameters, ...))

roots = []
parentless = {}
for id, name, parent_id in cursor:
    children = tuple(parentless.pop(id, ()))
    object = TreeNode(id, name, children)
    if parent_id is not None:
        parentless.setdefault(parent_id, []).append(object)
    else:
        roots.append(object)
```

If you are using an ORM which produces instances of mapped model classes, you only need to replace the loop over a cursor with a loop over the ORM result (still using the same order), removing the `object = TreeNode(...)` line, and retrieving the `id`, and `parent_id` values from the objects the ORM has produced for you. Set the children as a new list or tuple attribute on each object.

Because the leaf nodes, located at the highest `depth` value, are processed first, by the time their parent node is being processed all child nodes have already been processed and added to a `parentless[id]` list. If there were any child nodes for the current node, then `parentless.get(id, ())` will be produce a sequence of them.

However, if you are using an existing ORM, *don't reinvent this wheel*. Don't use an adjacency table either, there are better SQL models for hierarchical data, such as a [closure table](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data), or a [Modified Preorder Tree Traversal](https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/). For Django, there are [a series of options available](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/trees-and-graphs/), specifically [django-closuretree](https://github.com/ocadotechnology/django-closuretree), [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) or [django-treebeard](https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard). The latter supports adjacency list table structures, and it should be possible to move your existing models straight over to [it's support for adjacency lists](http://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/al_tree.html).

Comment: I didn't explain clearly, are multiple tress(updated) in the query(similar to categorization), your solution work with one root, in reality is a list of roots

Comment: @user3541631: then just use all a list for the roots.